# How to get ActivityResultRegistry in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

We already know how to get *ActivityResultRegistry* in **fragment** by using *getActivityResultRegistry* method. But how can I get *ActivityResultRegistry* in a **composable**?

There is a way to get the instance by using this code:

```
LocalActivityResultRegistryOwner.current?.activityResultRegistry
```

but it is **nullable**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It "is nullable" in the same sense as it "is nullable" when you are obtaining an `ActivityResultRegistry` from within a fragment.

The method `getActivityResultRegistry` is not a method available on the `Fragment` class. It is a method that belongs to the interface `ActivityResultRegistryOwner` that the `ComponentActivity` implements.

Since the `FragmentActivity` extends the `ComponentActivity` the same method becomes available also when using fragments, but the method itself is still called on an instance of an `ActivityResultRegistryOwner`. So the call still requires you to have a reference to an object from a class that either implements `ActivityResultRegistryOwner` or extends from a class that does that.

Inside a fragment you would usually access it like this (Java code).

```java
requireActivity().getActivityResultRegistry();
```

What this actually does is the following (Java code)

```java
FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
if (activity == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to an activity.");
}
activity.getActivityResultRegistry();
```

So semantically equivalent code in Compose would be (Kotlin code)

```kotlin
LocalActivityResultRegistryOwner.current!!.activityResultRegistry
```

[The not-null assertion operator (!!)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an `NullPointerException` if the value is `null`.

The main difference between the way the `ActivityResultRegistry` is obtained in fragments and the way it is obtained in Compose is that in the case that the `ActivityResultRegistryOwner` does not exist, it throws a different Exception type in fragments than it does in Compose.
Accessing it from the Fragment would throw an `IllegalStateException("Fragment ... not attached to an activity.")` while accessing it in Compose would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

I am assuming that you are using Compose inside a `ComponentActivity` anyway, so you will never receive a `null` reference when accessing `ActivityResultRegistryOwner.current`, so if you do not want to deal with a nullable type, you can use the `!!` operator.