# Android Activity Result API with a ViewModel: how to reference ActivityResultRegistry

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, activity-result-api

I am using Jetpack Compose and Dagger-Hilt in making an app with Bluetooth functionality, one of my objectives is to be able to make the device discoverable from inside the app.

I am seriously surprised of the fact that there is no mention of this problem on SO or elsewhere, even though this problem seems to be easily encounterable: to launch a system activity, like picking a photo, opening settings or prompting a user to enable Bluetooth discoverability, [ActivityResultLauncher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher) should be registered in the [ActivityResultRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultRegistry) and then launched.

Since I have a single ComponentActivity, no Fragments, am using Jetpack Compose, and certainly separating UI from any logic, it only makes sense to call such logic from a ViewModel, that is why I am surprised I haven't managed to find info about it anywhere. Not talking about the fact that even with Fragments a ViewModel should be used.

In order to achieve this I've tested the code below in a separate app with success (upon a button press and a call to `becomeDiscoverable()` a native Android dialog pops up requesting the discovery, at least on Android 8, on Android 10 there is no dialog, but it still works), but I am still unsure of stability of such code:

```
class MainViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    private val context: Application,
    @Assisted private val registry: ActivityResultRegistry,
) : ViewModel() {

var enableDiscoverableLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>? = null
        private set

fun becomeDiscoverable(duration: Int = 20) {
            enableDiscoverableLauncher = registry.register(
                "DISCOVERABLE_ENABLER", ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
            ) { }
            val requestCode = 1;
            val discoverableIntent: Intent =
                Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE).apply {
                    putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, duration)
                }
            enableDiscoverableLauncher?.launch(discoverableIntent, ActivityOptionsCompat.makeBasic())
        }

    //@AssistedFactory is below...
}
```

The thing is, since ViewModel outlives Activity, I am assuming during a configuration change the main ComponentActivity, which is the [ActivityResultRegistryOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultRegistryOwner) , would recreate, and if during that window the `becomeDiscoverable()` is called, the app would crash. I wasn't able to recreate this behavior, but I assume it to be the case.

After the activity's recreation the reference to activityResultRegistry in the viewModel still holds and the `becomeDiscoverable()` still can be successfully called.

According to the accepted answer to the question ["How to get ActivityResultRegistry in Jetpack Compose?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76026215/how-to-get-activityresultregistry-in-jetpack-compose/76026853#76026853) and my assumptions, I could obtain and remember `LocalActivityResultRegistryOwner.current!!.activityResultRegistry` at a certain point in composition to then use Dagger-Hilt's Assisted injection to obtain a viewmodel that would hold a reference to the activityResultRegistry.

But the last part of the answer really confused me:

> I am assuming that you are using Compose inside a ComponentActivity anyway, so you will never receive a null reference when accessing ActivityResultRegistryOwner.current, so if you do not want to deal with a nullable type, you can use the !! operator.

*How can it be the case? Why is it related specifically to ComponentActivity? And there is certainly no mention of a ViewModel in the linked question/answer, how is the OP not using vm at all?*

And most importantly,

**what is the correct way of implementing in Jetpack Compose interactions with such references of objects that are originally created by Android and belong to the main Activity?**